# svg tag in bootstrap data-content attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have an svg sprite sheet from which I can render images using

```
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/IconSpriteSheet.svg#duck"></use>
</svg>
```

I would like to use the images from the sprite sheet in a bootstrap 3 drop down but adding the svg tag to the data-content attribute in my option tag doesn't work :-(

I have tried just referencing the image using

```
<img src="/assets/IconSpriteSheet.svg#duck">
```

but that does not work. I guess this has to do with the structure of my sprite sheet.

Is what I'm trying at all possible?

**edit:** Here's the start of my svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="duck" viewBox="0 0 90.4 75.8">
    <path fill="none" d="M59.7,21.2c0.9,4.8,5.2,7.5,8.9,5.9c0.6-0.2,1-0.6,1.5-1c-2.1,0.2-4.2-2-4.4-5.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2
    c-0.2-3.7,2.1-6.3,4.4-6.1c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.7-1.1-1c-4.1-3.1-10.2,1.2-9.3,7.3C59.6,21,59.
```

Comment: An image must be complete in a single file, does IconSpriteSheet.svg have any external references e.g. css or images?

Comment: Nope. The svg sprite sheet is standalone.

Comment: What's duck? If it's a symbol then those are not directly renderable.

Comment: "duck" is just the id in the svg file: id="duck" for the image I want to render. :-)

Comment: Please see my edit to OP

Comment: As I hinted at, symbol elements are only renderable via being pointed at by a use element and not any other element.